# Getting selenium ElementNotVisibleException with Doctype

Tags: selenium-webdriver

I am using selenium selenium-java-2.1.0.jar, selenium-server-standalone-2.1.0.jar
On a particular page which has HTML and flash both . I am getting

**org.openqa.selenium.ElementNotVisibleException: Cannot click on element (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)****

Selenium is able to find the webelement but was not able to click on it. What I observed is after removing the  doctype 
**<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">** it started working absolutely fine.  Is there any fix to it because I cannot remove doctype decaration from the page.

Comment: Can you provide the HTML and your Test code?

Comment: What browser are you seeing the behavior on? All browsers? Just one?